# Obter o valor $1 do preg_replace dentro de uma array que tem dentro uma execução de uma função

Tags: php, preg-replace

Bom, quero mudar um texto de uma frase por outro (é tipo uma criptografia)

codigo sendo usado:

```
$dd = array();

$UserInfo = new UserInfo;

$search = array(
    '/log\((.*)\);/'
);

$replace = array(
    'log("' . $UserInfo->encrypt_text('$1', $dd) . '");'
);

$buffer = preg_replace($search, $replace, $buffer);
```

O que eu estou querendo fazer é o seguinte... se a frase for:

```
log("Ola");
```

eu quero pegar essa parte do ( Ola ) e enviar naquela função ali em baixo para executar a Criptografia, se eu usar o $1 fora da função, funciona normal, porem ao colocar dentro não funciona

Desde ja, agradeço

Comment: Utilize [**preg_replace_callback**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

Comment: Opa, coloquei essa função e não deu certo :/ o problema parece cer na forma que inseri o $1 no segundo array, porem já tentei de toda maneira :/

Comment: @ValdeirPsr Está impossibilitado em responder? Tenho notado que vc só comenta.

Comment: @dvd Não há problemas (técnicos) em responder. Apenas uma das formas de responde-los rapidamente (em alguns casos).

Comment: @SnowRunescape Seria isto https://ideone.com/vq7EzF ?

Comment: @ValdeirPsr Psr ,  Funcionou, muito obrigado :)